# (Recursive Entry Error) Fragment requests "replace fragment" action through MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have encountered a strange error while performing a replace fragment action in an activity.

**App includes**

- Main Activity
- Fragment A
- Fragment B

**Program Flow**

- main Activity started
- add fragment A to main activity's container
- a button in fragment A is clicked
- fragment A performs call back to main activity through interface
- when call back in main activity is received, perform a replace transaction to place fragment B to main activity's container

**The code below receives the following error** (MainActivity.java)

1894-1894/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1471) .. . .. . . .

```
@Override
public void presentSignInScreen() {
    replaceFragment(SignInFragment.newInstance(3), true);
}

// replace fragment in an activity if it is not exists
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    String fragmentTag = backStateName;

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null) {
        //fragment is not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        if (addToBackStack == true) {
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**The code below runs without error**  (MainActivity.java)

```
 @Override
public void presentSignInScreen() {
    // show login screen
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, SignInFragment.newInstance(3));
    ft.commit();
}
```

I am wondering what makes the "Recursive entry Error" occurs? And how could it be solved.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had same Issue when i was dealing with Fragments.
I was doing two things wrong.
1. I was adding new fragment with attached to root as true(in oncreateview)
2. I was providing same TAG to all the fragments but fragment with that tag was already popped up from backstace and i was trying to replace it.
I hope it helps

Comment: The attached to root has been set to false and the TAG should be uniquely generated based on class name, so it should not be the causes of the error.
But thanks for your opinion.